# num_rows not working in php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

1. I am trying to get particular row one by one like this :

   ```
   while($getRowCount = $query->fetch_assoc()){

   $uid = $getRowCount['ID'];
   ```
2. Next, I am selecting the row where this correspondingly matches in the second table as below:

   ```
   $getFullName = $db->prepare("SELECT * from registered_users where id = ?");
   $getFullName->bind_param("i",$uid);
   $getFullName->execute();
   if(($getFullName = $getFullName->num_rows) == 1){
       echo 'code reach';
       $getname = $getFullName->fetch_assoc();
       $FirstName = $getname['first_name'];
       $LastName = $getname['last_name'];
       echo '
         <br/>   
         <div id ="connect" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 15px; color: #CF0B05;">
         <strong>'.$FirstName.' '.$LastName.'</strong>
         </div><hr/>';                                
    }

    }
   ```

The issue is num_rows == 1 does not return true despite of there being a match in the table for this row.

Also, if I forcefully evaluate to num_rows == 0, it echoes out 'code reach' but attaches a couple errors with itself. I do not get the point why num_rows == 1 does not return true despite there being a row.

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/pages.php on line 634

 Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on integer in /var/www/html/pages.php on line 635
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your expression: `($getFullName = $getFullName->num_rows) == 1`

You are first setting `$getFullName` equal to the number of rows (integer) then seeing if it equals `1`.  Then you later try to access `$getFullName` as an object:

```
$getname = $getFullName->fetch_assoc();
```

So of course you get the error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on integer in /var/www/html/pages.php on line 635
```

Why are you setting `$getFullName` equal to the number of rows?   This is a simple case of understanding what each line of your code actually does.

Comment: aw, snap, I just realized that I am not using $getPostFullName = $getPostFullName->get_result(); before evaluating.

It works fine now. Also, yes I guess I am doing it wrong writing it $getFullName = $getFullName->num_rows) == 1. Changed

Thank you for pointing to the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace your if condition

```
if(($getFullName = $getFullName->num_rows) == 1)
```

with

```
if((getFullName = mysqli_num_rows($getFullName)) == 1)
```

for more about mysqli_num_rows function you can visit [click here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)